# Adding textfile data to Derby Database

Tags: java

I have code for reading data from a textfile and splitting it from the hastags. The data is currently stored in an array.
I am also using a Derby Database on Netbeans, so my question is, now that the data is separated, how would I insert this data into my Derby Database.

Input Data in Text File:

```
569#Chandini#Singh#58#24#89     
425#Angel#Dan#67#58#26     
780#Red#Velvet#48#21#10
```

Input Data (after splitting hastags) which needs to be inserted into Derby Database:

```
569 Chandini Singh 58 24 89     
425 Angel Dan 67 58 26      
780 Red Velvet 48 21 10
```

This is the current insert code which I have written:

```
     Studenttbl std = new Studenttbl();
     std.setStudentid(Short.parseShort(Id.getText()));
     std.setName(name.getText());
     std.setSurname(surname.getText());
     std.setIt(Integer.parseInt(it.getText()));
     std.setPhysics(Integer.parseInt(physics.getText()));
     std.setMaths(Integer.parseInt(math.getText()));

     StudyDBPUEntityManager.getTransaction().begin();
     StudyDBPUEntityManager.persist(std);
     StudyDBPUEntityManager.getTransaction().commit();

     studenttblList.clear();
     studenttblList.addAll(studenttblQuery.getResultList());

     iterator = studenttblList.listIterator(0);
     setStudents(iterator.next());

     System.out.println("Inserted");
```

This code currently inserts from textFields.

Thanks

Comment: Show an example of the input you would like to store.

Comment: 569 Chandini Singh 58 24 89

Comment: And where are the hastags? Please describe in detail the input format and provide a complete sample.

Comment: 569#Chandini#Singh#58#24#89 ;
425#Angel#Dan#67#58#26 ; 
780#Red#Velvet#48#21#10
- This is the textfile data.  Initially I had stored the data in a 1-D array, but realized now that I need a 2-D array. So I am currently working on code for writing the textfile data to a 2-D array

Comment: Please edit your question and add the input data to it. It is hard to read it in a comment.

Comment: Thank you. I hope that is easier to read !